# Why i don't read data at POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, web

i learn node and have problem. why i don't read data at my POST request? When i send my POST at html, if with req.method POST is work, but emmit 'data' doesn't work. 
This is part of my html:

```
<form method="post" action='./script.js'>
<label for="my-form">Enter phraze</label><input type="text" id='my-form'><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

let fs   = require('fs');
let http = require('http');

let server = http.createServer( (req, res) => {

  res.setEncoding = 'utf8';
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});

  if(req.url == '/'){
   reply('./index.html', res)
  }
  if(req.method == 'POST'){
   let body;
   req.on('data',
    (chunk) => { if(chunk != null) {body += chunk.toString(); res.write(chunk.toString())} })
   req.on('end',
    () => res.end(body) )
 }

}).listen(5858);

server.on('error', (err) => { throw err.message });

function reply(path, res){
  let streamPage = fs.createReadStream(path, {encoding: 'utf8'});

  streamPage.on('readable',
    (chunk) => { chunk = streamPage.read(); if(chunk != null) res.write(chunk) });
  streamPage.on('end',
    (out) => res.end());
  streamPage.on('error', (err) => err.message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You send post request to script file, it's not correct. You should set route to you server in action field.

```
<form method="post" action='/'>
<label for="my-form">Enter phraze</label><input type="text" id='my-form'><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Something like this.

Comment: fixed as in you. but it doesn't work. in my script file i don't entred to my callback in 'data'

Comment: @КостяМатюшонок It's my mistake, sorry. Your HTML don't know anything about routing of your node server. If you send post request via CURL or fiddler, you enter to your callback. If you want to send request via HTML page, replace action='/' to action=' http://localhost:5858/' or use express.js for useful routing and templates.